# Capturing dot1q packets with Wireshark on a PC

Tags: cisco, wireshark, dot1q

I have spent the last few hours trying to capture some trunk packets so I can see and examine the dot1q VLAN field. I have tried mirroring the trunk port to my PC using the following commands on Cisco 2960PD switch;

```
sh run | s mon
monitor session 1 source interface Fa0/6
monitor session 1 destination interface Fa0/4 encapsulation replicate
```

This has allowed me to capture the packets however I do not see the dot1q field as if the tag has been stripped out. I have tried some new drivers with my network adapter and I have tried changing the 'Priority and VLAN' setting to 'Priority and VLAN disabled' on my network adapter with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Far too many NICs (and drivers) internally process tags, so the OS never gets to see them.

Comment: Very often, there's a registry setting for the NIC to expose Q tags, see https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/VLAN

Comment: *Priority and VLAN* disabled probably means 802.1q disabled.  The *priority and VLAN* terminology is a good description of 802.1q.  So, you should probably NOT disable that option.

Comment: Actually, 802.1Q tags are on the ethernet frames, not the IP packets..

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the desired outcome by using a Mikrotik routerboard and getting the trunk to run through it. I used the packet sniffer function which saved the capture to a file and I was able to download the file to my PC and view it with Wireshark. The 802.1Q field was a sight for sore eyes :).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **Realtek** network adapter, try this:

1. Open **Device Manager**.
2. Find your network adapter and click on it to open the settings.
3. Click on the **Advanced** tab.
4. Click on **Priority & VLAN**.
5. Set it to **Priority & VLAN Disabled**.
6. Restart Wireshark and try again.

It's counter-intuitive, but it worked for me and quite a few other people.

### Update:

I just did this again for a second device. This one required the steps above, as well as the following:

7. Open the following path on your **Registry Editor**: *Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}*
8. Go through the network device entries numbered *00nn* till you find your network adapter.
9. Set the **MonitorModeEnabled** to **1**.
10. Restart your PC.